# Pulseaudio starts and crashes silently?

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I am using Manjaro Linux and a while ago pulseaudio has stopped working (after an update, I assume, I did not change any configuration manually).

The symptoms:

- In KDE, no sound device is found
- Pulseaudio volume control cannot connect to Pulseaudio
- ps x | grep pulse returns no running processes.
- pulseaudio -k says no pulseaudio process is running.
  However, Applications still play music using the speakers. I just cannot adjust the volume.

When running "pulseaudio" I get the following output

```
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
N: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
N: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
N: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
zsh: killed     pulseaudio
```

When I run "pulseaudio -D -v" I get the following output:

```
[pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup successful.
```

When I run "pulseaudio -k" afterwards it says it cannot abort the process because it could not been found. Also, "ps x | grep pulse" does not list any running process.

Any hints how to fix this?